# how to solve magento error - dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Tags: magento

if anyone can help on this issue it would be greatly appreciated. We have just built an ecommerce site using magento community edition 1.7. Our site was installed and working, in fact we were ready to go live today but now when we go to the site or CMS login we receive the following error.

dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

It was working this morning and I was about to purchase the extended site maps extension and install when I came across this error. It can’t be the extension though because I hadn’t even purchased it.

Does any one know any other possible explanations and how to rectify?

You can view our site here: http://bseatedglobal.cast-control.net/admin

Comment: I am also facing similar issue when migrating my live site to development server.How you fixed this?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your file permissions on just the `/var` folder to `777`. You may also need a 777 on the `/var/sessions`, `/var/cache` folders

or may be if your could not able to solve so another reason

check that  and  sections are defined under .

```
<resources>
       <dummy_setup>
         <setup>
           <module>IVVYRU_Dummy</module>
         </setup> 
         <connection>
           <use>core_setup</use>
         </connection>
       </dummy_setup>
       <dummy_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
       </dummy_write>
       <dummy_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
       </dummy_read>
     </resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It was occuring because I had changed database user, and password to that of the root user.

After going through a lot of anwsers, involving permission checks on folders, clearing cache, i finally reverted my installation to the original user, that was first used when i installed magento, and voila!

Comment: My Magento version was 1.7.0.2, CE.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your model extended class. It should be proper child folder and path.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Mysql4_Item extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init("module/test", "id");
    }
}
```